# How to disable inactive window shadowing in XFCE?

Tags: linux, xfce, xubuntu

In Xubuntu inactive windows are being shadowed, like on this example:
[image: Screenshot]

But I don't really like this behavior. How do I disable shadowing, so inactive windows would look like active ones?

Answer (score 1):

In Settings manager -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Compositor, there is a slider which is responsible tor opacity level. If you set it to maximal value, windows are no longer transparent.
[image]